# Laravel call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on boolean

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting the following error whenever i go on to a users page, its supposed to show if the authenticated user is already following the user that the profile is on.

Could this be a problem with the relationship setup, it `hasMany`

**Stack trace**

> local.ERROR: Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on
>   boolean {"userId":1,"email":"fakeemail@aol.com","exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0):
>   Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on boolean at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/elipost/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:522)"}
>   []

**UserController.php**

```
public function getProfile($user)
{  
    $users = User::with([
        'posts.likes' => function($query) {
            $query->whereNull('deleted_at');
            $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
        },
        'follow',
        'follow.follower'
    ])->with(['followers' => function($query) {
        $query->with('follow.followedByMe');
        $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
    }])->where('name','=', $user)->get();

    $user = $users->map(function(User $myuser){
        return ['followedByMe' => $myuser->followers->count() == 0];
    });


    if (!$user) {
        return redirect('404');
    }

    return view ('profile')->with('user', $user);
}
```

**MyFollow(model)**

```
<?php

class MyFollow extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, CanFollow, CanBeFollowed;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'followable_id'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'followables';

    public function follower()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'followable_id');
    }

    public function followedByMe()
    {
      return $this->follower->getKey() === auth()->id();
    }


}
```

**MyFollow**

```
use Overtrue\LaravelFollow\Traits\CanFollow;
use Overtrue\LaravelFollow\Traits\CanBeFollowed;

class MyFollow extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, CanFollow, CanBeFollowed;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'followable_id'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'followables';

    public function follower()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'followable_id');
    }

    public function followedByMe()
    {
      return $this->follower->getKey() === auth()->id();
    }


}
```

**Post**

```
class Post extends Authenticatable
{


    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'body',
        'user_id',
        'created_at',

    ];


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }

    public function likes()
    {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
    }

    public function likedByMe()
    {
        foreach($this->likes as $like) {
            if ($like->user_id == auth()->id()){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }






}
```

**Likes**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Like extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

     protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'post_id'
    ];



}
```

**User(model)**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable,CanFollow, CanBeFollowed;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);

    }


    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(GalleryImage::class, 'user_id');

    }


    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
    }

    public function follow()
    {   
        return $this->hasMany('App\MyFollow');
    }



    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }




}
```

Comment: Odd that you're chaining `::with(...)->with(...)`; you can just do `::with(["one" => function($q){ ... }, "two" => function($q){ ... }, "three", "four", ...])`. I don't think it causes an issue, cause you can chain methods such as `->where()`, but it looks off.

Comment: `followedByMe` is not a relationship. So you can't use `$query->with('follow.followedByMe')`.

Answer (score 1):

As Jonas Staudenmeir stated, followedByMe isn't a relationship, it's a regular function and what it does is returning a boolean. I'm confused at why you've got a follow on your user model and trying to get information from the follow's follower? Just simplify, I see too much unneeded eager loading here.

> Searching by indexed elements (id) > searching by name, any day of the week

Edit:

**UserController**

```
public function getProfile(Request $request, $id)
{  
    //$request->user() will get you the authenticated user
    $user = User::with(['posts.likes','followers','follows','followers.follows'])
    ->findOrFail($request->user()->id);
    //This returns the authenticated user's information posts, likes, followers, follows and who follows the followers 
    //If you wish to get someone else's information, you just switch 
    //the $request->user()->id to the $id if you're working with id's, if you're
    //working with names, you need to replace findOrFail($id) with ->where('name',$name')->get() and this will give you
    //a collection, not a single user as the findOrFail. You will need to add a ->first() to get the first user it finds in the collection it results of
    //If you're planning on getting an attribute (is_following = true) to know if
    //the authenticated user is following, you can use an accessor in the User model and write this after you've fetched the instance of the User
    //$user->append('is_following');
    return view ('profile')->with('user', $user);
}
```

**User Model**

```
//Accessor
//People who this user follows
public function getIsFollowingAttribute()
{   
    return MyFollow::where('followable_id',$this->attributes['id'])->where('user_id',Auth()->user()->id)->count() > 0 ? true : false;
}
//Relationships
//People who this user follows
public function follow()
{   
    return $this->hasMany('App\MyFollow','user_id','id');
}
//People who follows this user
public function followers()
{   
    return $this->hasMany('App\MyFollow','followable_id','id');
}
//Posts of this user
public function posts()
{   
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post','user_id','id');
}
//Likes of this user, not sure about this one tho, we're not using this for now but it could come in handy for you in the future
public function likes()
{   
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Likes','App\Post','user_id','user_id','id');
}
```

**Post Model**

```
//Who like this post
public function likes()
{   
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post','user_id','id');
}
```

**MyFollow Model**

```
//Relationships
//People who follow this user
public function followers()
{   
    return $this->hasMany('App\MyFollow','followable_id','user_id');
}
//Relationships
//People who this user follows
public function follow()
{   
    return $this->hasMany('App\MyFollow','user_id','followable_id');
}
```

Comment: `Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/elipost/resources/views/profile.blade.php)`

Comment: its messes up the structure of the $user variable, would you recommend something else

Comment: oh i didnt add the your snipped above the followedByMe let me give that a shot.

Comment: Yeah it doesnt work, just more errors, i think the way its set up now is fine, i think that there is something else wrong, maybe it could be the model, your code breaks everything else on my end.

Comment: Give me the schema of your tables (MyFollows, Post, Likes and User) and I'll edit my post  (edit your post with it)

Comment: Sorry, misswrote what I meant, you can delete the schemas, post your models relationships. I'm updating my answer as we speak

Comment: I don't have my editor in hand to test the code but it should work as it is now, I've commented some stuff in order for you to understand. If it's getting too much, my advise would be to go slowly and test fetching one at a time, the relationship's sons one after the other

Comment: let me give this a go

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174684/discussion-between-abr-and-barnowl).

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @abr i found a simple fix, simple solution.

**MyFollow.php(model)**

```
public function followers()
{   
    return $this->hasMany('App\MyFollow','followable_id','user_id');
}
//Relationships
//People who this user follows
public function follow()
{   
    return $this->hasMany('App\MyFollow','user_id','followable_id');
}
```

**User.php(model)**

```
public function getIsFollowingAttribute()
{   
    return MyFollow::where('followable_id',$this->attributes['id'])->where('user_id',Auth()->user()->id)->count() > 0 ? true : false;
}


public function follow()
{   
    return $this->hasMany('App\MyFollow');
}
```

**UserController.php**

```
 public function getProfile($user)
    {  
        $users = User::with(['posts.likes' => function($query) {
                            $query->whereNull('deleted_at');
                            $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
                        }, 'followers','follow.followers'])

                        ->with(['followers' => function($query) {


                        }])->where('name','=', $user)->get();

        $user = $users->map(function(User $myuser){

            $myuser['followedByMe'] = $myuser->getIsFollowingAttribute();

            return $myuser;
        });


        if(!$user){
            return redirect('404');
        }

        return view ('profile')->with('user', $user);
    }
```

it works now. :)